# "I was too quick to judge" vs "I was too fast to judge"

Tags: idiomatic-language, synonyms

I see that "quick" in "I was too quick to judge" is more widely used than "fast". What is the explanation for this? Is "fast" better suited for objects moving at high speed or is "quick" just more idiomatic?

Similarly: "I was too quick to ...":

- respond
- accept
- give up
- shoot

Comment: Little or no difference. God, it is said, is 'slow to chide but swift to bless'.

Comment: Contrary to what @Michael says, I would use "quick" for all of your examples and I might go as far as saying that "fast" is *incorrect*, or at least non-idiomatic. But that may be personal preference.

Comment: @randomhead - I tend to agree. I see lots of hits for "I was too fast to judge" and they are mainly (1) US-looking in origin (2) casual or informal (Trip Advisor, forum comments, etc). I see 'quick' here having the nuance of 'hasty' rather than just 'rapid'.

Comment: "Quick to judge" is idiomatic, even in America.

Comment: According to Google Ngrams, *quick to judge* is so much more common than *fast to judge* that it's not even really a contest: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fast+to+judge%2Cquick+to+judge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfast%20to%20judge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquick%20to%20judge%3B%2Cc0  (even if you choose the American English corpus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Fast' and 'quick' have a difference in meaning.

- 'Fast' relates to *speed*. Something that *is* fast might always be fast. For example, you might say that a jet plane *is* fast, even when it's standing still. 'Fast' is a quality it possesses.
- 'Quick' relates to *time*. If something was 'quick' it means that *it happened in a short space of time* - that might be as a result of being fast, but it can also relate to other things. For example, a shorter route might make a journey quick, even when travelling at the usual speed.

Judgement is a thought process. You'll find that people say "quick thinking", not "fast thinking". Thought isn't really measured in terms of speed - someone who thinks quickly may have a more efficient process; or, as with your example, a quicker result may be due to a lack of consideration of certain factors.

So, the most idiomatic way of saying what you mean is "I was too *quick* to judge". This would mean that you judged quickly, in a short amount of time, and should have perhaps devoted more thought to it.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Very good point. To see the difference, someone may be "*a quick draw*" because they have "*the fastest hands in the West.*"